# WCF timeout problem using net.tcp binding with callbacks

Tags: c#, callback, wcf-binding

I'm using a net.tcp binding to send via callback data to the client (after client once "signed up" ) - problem is that the connection runs into time out - and when I later call a method to cancel the connection (sets a column in database) I receive errors, that the connection is faulted due to either security context token being invalid or service aborted the channel due to inactivity - but I already set the receiveTimeout to TimeSpan.MaxValue...

```
        ServiceHost host;
...
   var prog = new Program();
   prog.host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DataService), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:50111") });
   prog.StartServer();
...
        private void StartServer()
        {
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            OptionalReliableSession reliableSession=binding.ReliableSession;
            reliableSession.Enabled = true;
            reliableSession.Ordered = true;
            reliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
            this.host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDataService), binding, "DataService");
            this.host.Open();
        }
```

code on the client is using same connection parameters (timeout and so on)

How can I keep the connection alive until closing it willfully?

Answer (score 0):

NetTcpbinding secures the communication by using Windows authentication by default. 
The below definition is equivalent.

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
```

---

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

When the client calls the service, we should provide a pair of windows credentials to be authenticated by the server.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            //provides windows credentials in order to be authenticated by the server.
            //these credentials actually are the windows account on the server-side.
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abcd1234!";
```

In my opinion, the invocation will result in the timeout exception if we do not provide the windows credential.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.